# Understanding relationship between ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory and KafkaMessageListenerContainer with RangeAssignor in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In the docs it is stated that after you set `concurrency` on ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory you will get that many instances of KafkaMessageListenerContainer. Also, if you use `RangeAssignor` strategy, you should be seing 10 idel KafkaMessageListenerContainer. I cannot seem to understand why is that? I was reading [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#using-ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer) and tested:

I have this in my producer-ms:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("first_topic1")
                .partitions(5)
                .replicas(1)
                .compact()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("first_topic2")
                .partitions(5)
                .replicas(1)
                .compact()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic3() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("first_topic3")
                .partitions(5)
                .replicas(1)
                .compact()
                .build();
    }

}
```

In receiver-ms:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
        ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setConcurrency(15);
        return factory;
    }
```

Strategy:

```
 consumer:
  key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer
  value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
  auto-startup: true
  properties:
    partition:
      assignment:
        strategy: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor
```

And finally I do get those 10 idle `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`s:

```
2023-02-04T13:55:48.780+01:00  INFO 3960 --- [tainer#0-10-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : my-first-application: partitions assigned: [first_topic1-2, first_topic2-2, first_topic3-2]
2023-02-04T13:55:48.780+01:00  INFO 3960 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : my-first-application: partitions assigned: [first_topic1-0, first_topic2-0, first_topic3-0]
2023-02-04T13:55:48.780+01:00  INFO 3960 --- [tainer#0-11-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : my-first-application: partitions assigned: [first_topic1-3, first_topic2-3, first_topic3-3]
2023-02-04T13:55:48.780+01:00  INFO 3960 --- [ntainer#0-9-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : my-first-application: partitions assigned: [first_topic1-1, first_topic2-1, first_topic3-1]
2023-02-04T13:55:48.780+01:00  INFO 3960 --- [tainer#0-12-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : my-first-application: partitions assigned: [first_topic1-4, first_topic2-4, first_topic3-4]
```

Cannot seem to understand [Java docs for RangeAssignor](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RangeAssignor.html). Like we had 3 topics, 5 partitions each topic. Total 15. In docs, they say `'We then divide the number of partitions by the total number of consumers'`. What is a consumer in this case? Is it my microservice which joins consumer group or is all fifteen `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`s?

Then it says: `'If it does not evenly divide, then the first few consumers will have one extra partition'`, but this does divide evenly 15/3=5.

Would really like some help here.

Second thing that is related, why should we ever choose RangeAssignor over CooperativeStickyAssignor since with RangeAssignor always the first consumers are getting more partitions and it is eager strategy i.e. it entails stop-the-world event while CooperativeStickyAssignor does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentance of the documentation that you've linked states explicitelly:

> The range assignor works on a **per-topic basis**.

That means, that each of the three 5-partition topics is divided betwean consumers separetly. Since you have 15 consumers, first 5 of them will receive one partition of each topic and the rest will stay idle.

Comment: It would be so much easier if they had provided some graphic examples. Sorry for my englsih, so separately, in this case means: First I'll take five partitions from first_topic1 and I'll place one by one on consumers (before that I'll sort consumer lexicographically), so first five consumers will be utilized and others (10 wont), Repeat the process for other two topcis. Is that the order of things?

Comment: @Wrapper Yes, exactly

Comment: The Spring documentation explicitly describes this situation and how to work around it: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#using-ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer for example, by using the `RoundRobinAssignor` instead. `>When listening to multiple topics, the default partition distribution may not be what you expect. For example, if you have three topics with five partitions each and you want to use concurrency=15, you see only five active consumers, each assigned one partition from each topic, ...`